# SQL Server: CASE statement in WHERE clause with IN condition

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use, in a stored procedure with @input as input value, a case statement in a where clause like this :

```
SELECT my_column
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_TABLE.my_column in (CASE WHEN @input = '1' THEN ('A','B','C') ELSE ('A') END)
```

Incredibly, it works when I place only one value after "THEN" like this :

```
SELECT my_column
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_TABLE.my_column in (CASE WHEN @input = '1' THEN ('C') ELSE ('A') END)
```

Can I use the `IN` condition with a `CASE` statement like I wanted above? Is there an another way to do what I want ?

Thank you for your help,

CLJ

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (just like `a+b`) - not a *statement* - which ultimately is replaced by one, single, atomic value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your first query is that `CASE` returns just a scalar value. It cannot return a list of values.

Instead, you can simply use `OR`:

```
SELECT  my_column
FROM    MY_TABLE
WHERE   (@input = '1' and MY_TABLE.my_column IN ('A','B','C'))
        OR
        (@input <> '1' and MY_TABLE.my_column = 'A')
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, why it does not work .... WHERE my_column in (@getval). SELECT @getval returns the string 'A', 'B', 'C'.

Comment: @Pinwar13  `'A', 'B', 'C' ` is *not* a *single* string of data. It is instead a *set* of three separate string values. `CASE` *cannot* return a set of values.

Comment: Thanks!, This is just for my learning. I understand CASE cannot return set of values. declare @getval varchar(100) = CASE WHEN input = '1' THEN ('''A'', ''B'', ''C''') ELSE ('A') END. Here I can get the string 'A', 'B', 'C' from CASE.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate answers. I better understand the use of CASE now. Thanks !